# Why Sitecore MVC Model.Rendering.Item Initialized with Page Item instead of View Rendering Datasource Item?

Tags: razor, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.5

I have an MVC View rendering in Sitecore 7.5 defined as:

```
Item Name: ViewRenderingA
Item Template: View Rendering
Path: /path/to/ViewRenderingA.cshtml
Data Source: {3AD25922-FE0E-45B3-9F2F-7EF61F678E45} // Item Id of the image in the media library
```

As you can see, this view rendering has its data source field set to the image item's GUID in the media library. Basically, I am trying to render an image from the media library in a particular static spot of the content item layout.

I statically pull this view rendering in the layout file as:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/path/to/ViewRenderingA")
```

And then in the Razor View implementation ViewRenderingA.cshtml file, I do this:

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
@model RenderingModel

<p>Page Item Name: @Model.PageItem.Name</p> @* <- This correctly shows the content item name. *@
<p>Rendering Name: @Model.Rendering.Item.Name</p> @* <- Why does this also show the content item name instead of the item name of the image in the media library that's linked to the View rendering via data source? *@
```

I would expect that the `Model.Rendering.Item` will be initialized with the media library item that the View Rendering's "Data source" field is pointing to, but it is initialized with the `Model.PageItem` instead. It looks like it completely ignores the datasource field. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you try to access the item with `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item`? Does it work when you add the datasource statically as a parameter to the binding like described in my blog post http://ctor.io/specify-datasource-item-of-a-statically-binded-rendering/?

Comment: `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item` also points to the content item (I think it's called "context item") as the other 2. It only works if I add the data source as a parameter  like this: `@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/path/to/ViewRenderingA", new { DataSource = "/path/to/datasource-item" })`. Looks like setting the "Data source" filed of the View rendering itself makes no difference.

Comment: Hm then I would probably add a new issue on https://support.sitecore.net.

Comment: If you set the datasource on the View rendering then I believe you can use: RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.RenderingItem.InnerItem. Not sure though, its been a while since I've used this.

Comment: Under normal circumstances RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item will work for getting the current renderings datasource.

Answer (score -1):

If you have given data source then you can access the item by using **Sitecore.Context.Item**

```
Item datasource = Sitecore.Context.Item;
```

And if your data source is not going to change then one workaround would be access it using its Item ID as:

```
dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ItemId);
```

In your case Item Id would be ID of your media library content
I hope this helps.